# Hosting console application in public service fabric cluster

Tags: azure-service-fabric

I am trying to deploy a console application to service fabric. I was able to successfully deploy and run the application in local service fabric cluster. But when I am trying with public service fabric cluster, I am seeing below warning in service fabric explorer and the application is not running.

> Unhealthy event: SourceId='System.Hosting',
>   Property='CodePackageActivation:C:EntryPoint', HealthState='Warning',
>   ConsiderWarningAsError=false.There was an error during CodePackage
>   activation.The service host terminated with exit code: 3762504530

Comment: Is it a .NET-based console app?

Comment: Yes it is a .Net console application

Comment: Basically it tells you that it failed to start. Common reasons we've seen is basically missing assemblies in the package. Could it be that you have a reference that's not copied to the output, and thus is not included in the package ?

Comment: Is there a way to check whether all the dlls have been copied correctly? I mean in local cluster, we can go and check the location C:\SfDevCluster\Data\_App. But for public cluster, how will we check? How can we connect to individul VM under Virtual machine scale sets?

Answer (score 11):

The most common explanation for code the runs locally but not in Azure is that you're targeting a .NET framework version that is not present on the VMs provisioned in a Service Fabric cluster. They currently provide .NET 4.5.1 out of the box, with .NET 4.5.2 getting added some time this month. Try retargeting your app to 4.5.1.

**Update**: as of February 2016, VMs provisioned for Service Fabric clusters come with .NET 4.5.2 by default.

Comment: Thank you for the information.
But my application is created in .Net framework 4.

Comment: @Sean is there any way to run .NET 4.6 applications in a Service Fabric cluster?

Comment: Yes, but you are responsible for getting .NET 4.6 onto the VMs since it does not come preinstalled on Server 2012 images. Most people are doing this using a custom VM extension.

Comment: I wonder why it's not a part of the default template? .NET 4.6 is not something new.

Comment: It's not about the template, it's about the VMs that make up your cluster in Azure. They are very close to base Windows images so they don't come with later versions of .NET preinstalled.

Comment: So we cannot use some Windows image which already has latest .NET framework, can we?

Comment: No. You can only get the base Windows image, which comes with 4.5.2.

Comment: Sean, what is the best way to diagnose issues like these? I do not see any kind of logs in the service fabric dashboard, and no clear way to view logs of the cluster in either the Azure Portal or in Visual Studio. Edit: I mean, I only see the log of the latest health event in the dashboard, which doesn't explain what the problem is.

Comment: I was targeting 4.6 and putting the service to 4.5.2 did the trick.

Comment: As of April, 2018, is .NET 4.5.2 still the default?