# Can IDataContractSurrogate be used with Azure reliable service and/or actors?

Tags: c#, azure, azure-service-fabric

Using Azure Service Fabric I'm trying to serialize Immutable types in stateful services and actors. Apparently there is no support in the data contract serializer but I could add it as shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18957739/158285) using an IDataContractSurrogate.

Is there some way to provide the serializer with my IDataContractSurrogate?

Comment: After looking at the KvsActorStateProvider it appears to be impossible without creating my own ActorStateProvider. This is because the constructor sets actorStateSerializer = new ActorStateProviderSerializer() and there is no way to change the ActorStateProviderSerializer or provide a custom implementation.

Comment: this is somewhat similar: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35578005/hosting-console-application-in-public-service-fabric-cluster

Answer (score 0):

If you define your immutable type similar to this, it works fine:

```
[DataContract]
public class Payload
{
    [DataMember]
    public readonly string Content;

    public Payload(string content)
    {
        Content = content;
    }
}
```

see [this article](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/service-fabric-work-with-reliable-collections/) too.

Comment: I cant do that. I should have been more clear, when I said immutable types I was referring to System.Collections.Immutable types.

Comment: check that article.. they use an immutable collection

Comment: Ok, I see that they have an IEnumerable member that is backed by an ImmutableList but that's different than directly serializing the ImmutableList. They have to rebuild the list in OnDeserialized. What I really want is the ability to store an immutable collection in a reliable actors storage. e.g. StateManager.SetStateAsync("list", myImmutableList);